# How to write multiple records on a single Hadoop node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing, apache-pig, hdfstore

I need help for a Hadoop problem. 
In my Java system, I have a function that creates *n* records. Each record obviously is a row to write in a text file in Hadoop.

The problem is: 
How can I save all the *n* records in the same Hadoop node? In other words, I want that the *n* records are seen like a unique record, to be sure that if one of these records (or one of its replica) is on a node, then of course the other *n-1* records are also on the same node.

For example, suppose that my function creates:

```
record1: 5     los angeles    rainy
record2: 8     new york       sunny
record3: 2     boston         rainy
```

When I append this three records (three rows) in the text file of Hadoop, it can happen that record1 goes to node1, record2 goes to node2 and record3 goes to node3. I want to know if there is a way to be sure that all three records are stored on the same node, for example node2, and that they are not stored on different nodes.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Sounds like you may want a custom partitioner to ensure a given pattern of keys ends up on a particular reducer.  However I think adding additional clarity to the question will help people better understand your question.

Comment: I have edit it, sorry if I didn't explain me

Comment: I may still be a bit confused by your question, so I apologize if this is not helpful.  If you set the number of reducers to 1, you will guarantee that all records are written to the same file, at the expense of your job taking longer to complete.  Otherwise, you can write a custom partitioner that will specify that keys meeting certain criteria end up at a particular reducer (i.e. 5 and 8 in one file, but 2 in another).  However the files will be in HDFS and thus replicated across several nodes regardless of which option you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop will partition the tuples based on the default HashPartitioner and send the tuples with the same key to a single reducers for aggregations. If the default HashPartitioner doesn't fit the requirement then a [custom partitioner](http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2012/05/hadoop-recipe-implementing-custom-partitioner/) can be written. [Here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/HashPartitioner.java) is the code for the HashPartitioner in the trunk.

Another way is to emit the keys from the mapper as per the partition strategy and the HashPartitioner will send all the tuples with the same key to one of the reducer.

Also, think at a Map and Reduce level abstraction and not a node level. Hadoop tries to hide the network topology of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

By setting your parallelism to one. That means by specifying your number of reducers to one. Then all your records would get written into one part file. But the downside is your job takes much longer time to complete.